# What does this empty string mean?

Tags: javascript, dom, stylesheet, cssom

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var step = 4;

        function expandPanel()

        {

            var panel = document.getElementById('panel');

            if ( panel.clientHeight < (panel.originalHeight-step))

            {

                //clientWidth

                var h = panel.clientHeight + step;

                panel.style.height = h+"px";

                setTimeout("expandPanel()", 100); 

            }

            else

            {

                panel.style.height = "";

                var panelTitle = document.getElementById('panelTitle');

                panelTitle.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Collapse';



            }

        }



        function collapsePanel()

        {

            var panel = document.getElementById('panel');



            if ( panel.clientHeight >= step)

            {

                var h = panel.clientHeight - step;

                panel.style.height = h+"px";

                setTimeout("collapsePanel()", 100);

            }

            else

            {

                panel.style.display = 'none';

                var panelTitle = document.getElementById('panelTitle');

                panelTitle.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Expand';

            }





        }



        function changePanel()

        {

            var panel = document.getElementById('panel');

            if (!panel.style.height || 

                (panel.style.display == 'none'))

            {

                if (panel.style.display == 'none')

                {

                    panel.style.display = '';

                    expandPanel();

                }

                else

                {

                    panel.originalHeight = panel.clientHeight;

                    collapsePanel();

                }

            }

        }

    </script>
```

There is an empty string assigned to the `height` and `display` CSS properties (via CSSOM).
What does it mean in this case?

Comment: Why do you have so many `newlines` separating each line your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it does is just wipes out that CSS property.  If the style attribute looked like this before:

```
<div style="height: 100px"></div>
```

It will now look like this:

```
<div style=""></div>
```

Comment: So, will default value be used??

Comment: You are confusing attributes and properties. The attribute may or may not exist, and may or may not have the same value as the property.

Comment: The default, or whatever properties are inherited via CSS will be used.  It depends on if any CSS rules apply to the elements.  @RobG, the style properties correspond directly to what ends up in the style attribute itself in firefox, looks like IE doesn't update the style tag though.

Comment: @SoWeLie - properties and attributes (style or otherwise) are not equivalent, please see my answer and test in multiple browsers.

Comment: @RobG, yeah they're not the same thing...obviously.  The style properties are a part of the DOM, while the style attribute is a part of the markup. However the results they produce are equivalent.  In Firefox and Google Chrome (and I'm assuming other Webkit based browsers), setting the style properties will indeed update the style attribute.  In IE, it does not cause an update of the style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `element.style` properties to '' (empty string) lets them adopt the inherited or default value.

For example, setting `element.style.display` to empty string it is the preferred way to show an element that was previously hidden with `display = 'none';`, that way you don't have to know what the original property was (it may not have been set at all).

Please note that in some browsers, changing a DOM property will modify the related HTML attribute but in other browsers it won't. Also, how the attribute is set it is implementation dependent. So do not rely on that behaviour, just deal with properties.

Try the following in a few browsers:

```
<div id="d0">div</div>
<button onclick="
  var el = document.getElementById('d0');
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  el.style.border = '1px solid blue';
  alert(el.getAttribute('style'));
">Do stuff</button>
```

**Firefox 5:** background-color: red; border: 1px solid blue;

**IE 8:** [object]

**Chrome 14:**  background-color: red; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: blue; border-right-color: blue; border-bottom-color: blue; border-left-color: blue;

**Opera 11:** background-color: #ff0000; border-top-color: #0000ff; border-left-color: #0000ff; border-right-color: #0000ff; border-bottom-color: #0000ff; border-top-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid

Answer (score 0):

This example should help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {
                height: 45px;
                width: 45px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: #ccc
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
                alert("That's the default size. Let's change it.");
                div.style.height = "200px";
                div.style.width = "200px";
                alert("Let's reset the size back to default.");
                div.style.height = "";
                div.style.width = "";
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```